# How to perform some actions onclicking different subitems of listview

Tags: android, android-animation, counting

**This is my ItemPriceActivity image:**

Here I have used URL of another API which is hosted, as it is ease for me to use this URL because I frequently don't need to change the address so I have used that one. So never mind with the names of hospitals presented over there.

[image]

**This is my Adapter class**

Here all I wanna do is when I click on subitems of listview i.e. on cart icon, I want an animation that shakes for the textview  which is presented just above the floating button and as on clicking different cart icons the number should also increase and also it should decrease while it is unchecked. 
Please suggest me that how can I perform such actions and thank you in advance.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ItemPricePojo userInfo = datalist.get(position);
            mlistener.onItemClick(userInfo);
        }
    });
     final TextView totalcart = convertView.findViewById(R.id.totalcartitems);
    final Animation animShake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.shake);
    final CheckBox checkBox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.addtocart);
    checkBox.setTag(new Integer(position));
    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            totalcart.startAnimation(animShake);

            if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                count++;
                totalcart.setText(Integer.toString(count));
            }
            else {
                count--;
                totalcart.setText(Integer.toString(count));

            }

        }
    });

    TextView price = convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

    ItemPricePojo m = datalist.get(position);

    price.setText(String.valueOf(m.getPrice()));
    name.setText(String.valueOf(m.getName()));

    return convertView;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set an onClick listener to your checkBoxes.
You should instead use setOnCheckedChangeListener which will tell you if the checkbox was checked or not.

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried using the same as you have said, but it is still throwing error in action performance code i.e. totalcart.startAnimation(animShake); I think there is some error in the code that I have to specify the textview or the animation code. Is there another way to perform those actions? It is throwing error in both conditions i.e. using animation and increasing textvalue...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to switch to the recyclerview as clicks are handled more effectively in that and checking out [this](https://github.com/matrixdevz/FlyToCartAnimation) article

Answer (score 0):

Finally after some great research I found my answer. All I have to do is to change the textview into static in my activity class which is not been recognized by my adapter class. I change:

public static textview totalcart = findViewById();

in my activity class. Since adapter class donot let to use findViewById(); so we have to use it as static in activity class. Now, I have to define my activity class from where I want textview to identify by adapter class:

ItemPriceActivity itemsPriceActivity = new ItemPriceActivity();

Then while using animation I did this:

final Animation animShake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mcontext, R.anim.shake);
itemsPriceActivity.totalcart.startAnimation(animShake);

Now, it works as I want it to .